# Target action is lost after adding animation to button

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

The following code is animating button in loop.

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount: 0];

self.introButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4
                      delay: 0.0
                      options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                      animations: ^{
                        self.introButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                      }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                        //Code
                      }];
```

However, after adding this animation, I am no more able to get button touch up inside action. How can I animate AND get action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option to your animation.

```
UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4
                  delay: 0.0
                  options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                  animations: ^{
                    self.introButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                  }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                    //Code
                  }];
```

The docs say:

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to interact with the views, include the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options parameter

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need separate the animation view and the view who is responsive to tap

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations: ^{
                     button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
                 }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                     //Code
                 }];

UIView *frontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
frontView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:frontView];
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
[frontView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

Comment: This will work, but it's really not necessary to go to this trouble.

Comment: @JesseRusak Yes you are right. Learn something new here :)